# Non-Stack Overflow link-only answers dilemma

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, declined-flags, review-suspension

I know this matter has been discussed several times before; however, I've reached a dilemma regarding this.

Previously I had raised a flag for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54006117/6059951), but it was declined. The message was:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Today I encountered an [almost same situation](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21862055) and reviewed the answer with `No Action Needed`. Unfortunately it was a test and costed me an 8-day suspension for reviewing. Why would the first answer be considered as a good answer, whereas the second one would get deleted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are two very different answers.

Your first, declined flag says *use this built-in function with these arguments, here's a link with further information*. That's a somewhat reasonable answer, as the name of the built-in function might be a sufficient answer.

The second says: *use this external library* with a link to the library and without telling you how to use it. That's not a good answer, since it doesn't really address the question, and just suggests taking a different approach altogether. While that might not be a link-only answer in the strict sense, it is a pretty bad answer.

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be a comment, instead of an answer?

Comment: Certainly not. It's a full answer, that function does exactly what the OP is asking for, and thus _use this function_ is a sufficient answer.

Comment: @iminiki Why do you think that the statement is an attempt to improve the question, rather than providing a solution to the problem described.

Comment: @Servy Because I assumed that in order to validate a linked-answer, you should copy and change the linked content to match the question.

Comment: @iminiki Answers are not forbidden from having links, they simply need to answer the question even if the reader doesn't follow the link.   *Adding* a link to an answer doesn't suddenly turn it into a non-answer when it was previously an answer.